# How to convert negativevalues to 0 mdx

Tags: ssas, mdx

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2, SSAS Enterprise  edition.

I want to know please how to convert negative values in my calculated measure into 0.

Thanks!

Galshan

Answer (score 0):

If you want to really show negative values as zero, then use something like

```
IIf(your_expression < 0, 0, your_expression)
```

where `your_expression` is the expression to calculate your expression. You could also use the `format_string` of the calculated measure to keep the value as it is, but just display it to users as zero, provided the client tool they use honors the format_string or formatted_value. The format string would be something like

```
'#;0'
```

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146084(v=sql.105).aspx for details of the format_string.